# Which is better to use between realtime database or firestore in firebase?

Tags: firebase

I am currently working in android studio and i have designed a login page now i want to do some backend work so i connected my app to the firebase now on firebase console in databse there are realtime database and firestore i want to know which would be easy to understand and connect in firebase?

Comment: Off topic... but I like "a variable is a name that is used to point at a location in memory that contains some type of data".

Comment: Means what i said above is correct

Comment: Variables don't need to 'point to a location in memory'.  If, for example, I write ```int x = 42;``` a compiler is under no obligation just because of that declaration to allocate any storage at all for ```x```.  If, for example, I subsequently write ```someCall(x);```, the compiler may be able to determine it's perfectly fine to use a literal 42 as the value of the argument.

Answer (score 1):

A variable in any programming language has the following attributes.
A variable is nothing but a box, which can hold a value. What value it can hold, how much space it occupies, and how do we access the box to get the value from it are the difference in varied programming languages.

1. Type

Type of the variable determines what can be stored in the variable. In strictly typed languages like java and c++ a variable once initialized to a certain type cannot be changed. But in dynamically typed programming languages like python, the variable can be reassigned to value of different types (int to float)

2. size/memory

How much memory does the value of the variable holds ( box size)

3. name

How do we address/access the variable to access its values.

4. scope/accessibility

What is the accessibility range of the variable, if declared globally any function can use it or is it local to a specific function.

There is more to it when you have the concept of reference variables, which points to the object. (which you will be able to grasp when you are into object-oriented programming)